# Why in Java my CPU bound threads can cause operations in kernel space?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

I have large array of type C and a pool of threads. Each thread has a range of indexes (they don't overlap) and does some CPU bound operations to populate them.

After submission of tasks to the executor (created with newFixedThreadPool) I monitor the output of 'top' command and can notice that the cpu spends significant amount of time in kernel space ("%sy" in 'top' output) - between 15 and 25% - during the execution of those tasks (before it is low and after it decreases again).
On some test runs it does happen that "%sy" stays close to 0 and then the execution is much faster.

The number of threads is equal to the number of logical cpus on the test machine and this is also the number of tasks that I submit to the executor (so it's like 1 thread - 1 CPU bound task). Therefore I wouldn't expect here a lot of context switching.

In this part of code there is no explicit synchronization done by me, I rely only on the guarantees provided by the executor service as the threads don't share any variables.

Operating system is Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09, the program runs on Java 8.

Any ideas why this could happen? How I can debug such issue?

Comment: Are you running this in a VM on shared hardware? Can you reproduce the problem on a dedicated machine?

Comment: It runs on an aws ec2 instance. I haven't tried it on the dedicated machine.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a [Profiler](http://www.bing.com/search?q=java%20profiler&src=IE-TopResult&FORM=IE10TR)